What's the best way to iterate over/parse df.collect() in pyspark (unusual data format)?
I'm using Databricks pyspark, reading an s3 object but it's not a usual CSV. It has headers and data in the middle of the file so I read it in like this.
df = (spark.read
    .format("text")
    .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("inferSchema","false")...

So df.collect() gives me:
[Row(value=':::::'),
 Row(value='./some_file_name.csv'),
 Row(value=':::::'),
 Row(value='col_one|col_two|col_three'),
 Row(value='1|2|3'),
 Row(value='./another_file.csv'),
 Row(value='more stuff|of|varying|length')]

I need to get at col_one, col_two and the line immediately after it with 1, 2, 3, etc.
I can iterate as a list and do a regex, but is there a more efficient or preferred way? I'm aware iterating over dataframes is considered inefficient.
The data volume is not so big so I'm not concerned about time/resources. Just wondering what the most "pyspark" thing to do is.

As can be seen in this post, you can use the rlike function on a column to filter the dataframe with the regular expression you are now using to iterate over the collected dataframe. Another option since Spark 3.5.0, is the pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_like or the pyspark.sql.functions.regexp function.
I don't think there is a more "pyspark thing to do" as you describe, as your problem not standard at all in my opinion. The only thing I can think of otherwise is if your required data is in a fixed set of rows, to just take those rows into consideration and validate that it is as expected, as it is already not standard at all. That might be a neat way to do preprocessing if such a thing is possible in your scenario.
